# How to select rows every record+100 value?

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table of integer, with two columns.

- col1 | col2
- 47 | 99
- 56 | 100
- 100 | 110
- 147 | 150
- 156 | 160
- 200 | 250
- 247 | 300

Let's say MySQL starts to read at col1, row1, the values are 47 and 99. 
What I want MySQL to do, is to select data from col1 every values+100. 
So here col1 starts at 47, MySQL should select
47
147
247

FYI : this table has about 500.000 rows. .. According to stats, this should return about 50,000 rows. So I need a super-fast query.

I had several attempt that didn't work out, with smth like that:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM ( 
           SELECT 
                @row := @row +100 AS rownum, col1
           FROM (SELECT @row :=0) r, my_table 
           ) ranked 
    WHERE rownum % [n] = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do something like

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE col1 % 100 = 
   (select col1 % 100 from mytable order by col1 limit 1)
```